# CSS Transition delaying DOM/scope update in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, css-transitions

It seems when I apply css transitions, the dom/scope updates get delayed as well.

I have a list that can be paged. When the top div wrapper of each list-element `.tl-container`

```
<div class="tl-container" ng-repeat="elem in analysisMetaList.list">
 ...
</div>
```

gets the css transition

```
.tl-container {
    ...
    transition: background-color 150ms ease-out; /* for smoother hover effect*/
}
.tl-container:hover {
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
}
```

The updates are delayed and I can see the old list for the transition time (so if it would be 3 sec, the old list would stay there for 3sec):

[image: showcase delayed]

wheras when I only delete this css transition and keep everything else the same, it works as expected:

[image: showcase normal]

`analysisMetaList.list` is a normal array that will be filled through a http call (simplyfied code)

```
angular.module('app').controller('Ctrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {
    var analysisPerPage = 5;

    $scope.analysisMetaList={};

    function reloadAnalysisMetaList() {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: constants.getApiUrl() +"/analysis/",
            headers: {'If-None-Match': $scope.analysisMetaList.etag}})
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.analysisMetaList.list = data.splice(0,analysisPerPage);
                $scope.analysisMetaList.etag = headers("Etag");
            });
}]);
```

The whole page is data heavy, but fast enough - although it does not seem to have anything to do with performance.

As a side note: the same bug happend with simple `ng-show` (where entering a value in a textfield lets the textfield disappear and the not-editable value will be shown)

[I tryed recreating the bug with a simple plunkr but I couldn't.](http://jsfiddle.net/for3st/cak31rzo/) I additionally use the angular-route and angular-animate plugins.

Tested with angular 1.3 & 1.2 on chrome & firefox

---

Is this a known angular or javascript issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ngAnimate is going to use that css trasition timing to base any of the standard directives so ng-show and ng-repeat may wait on it and will put all of the css on that element style. You can try to cancel 
animation on that element with.

```
$animate.enabled(false, element);
```

Comment: You're right, it was the ng-animate module. I did not facilitate your solutions, since I didn't really need the module and just disabled it for the moment.